# running undetected_chromdriver on AWS Lambda: Message: 'e39098076c0be4f2_chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, dockerfile, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to deploy a python automation script on AWS lambda using docker image. and I'm sure I did everything right regarding the Path and the installtion, but when I run it on AWS I get this weird error message.

"errorMessage": "Message: 'e39098076c0be4f2_chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH."

what is wierd about it is that there is always a random string infront of chromedriver. the usual error message should be like:

"errorMessage": "Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH."

the complete log for the error I get:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Message: 'e39098076c0be4f2_chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home\n",
  "errorType": "WebDriverException",
  "requestId": "107a17da-65d4-4bec-a5dc-1e69c1b63fe7",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/home/app/app.py\", line 60, in lambda_handler\n    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=r\"/tmp/chromedriver\")\n",
    "  File \"/home/app/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py\", line 409, in __init__\n    super(Chrome, self).__init__(\n",
    "  File \"/home/app/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 69, in __init__\n    super().__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], \"goog\",\n",
    "  File \"/home/app/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py\", line 89, in __init__\n    self.service.start()\n",
    "  File \"/home/app/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py\", line 81, in start\n    raise WebDriverException(\n"
  ]
}
```

I have the executble file in Path but it's name is chromdriver.

my docker file:

```
# Define global args
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/home/app/"
ARG RUNTIME_VERSION="3.10"
ARG DISTRO_VERSION="3.16"

# Stage 1 - bundle base image + runtime
# Grab a fresh copy of the image and install GCC
FROM python:${RUNTIME_VERSION}-alpine${DISTRO_VERSION} AS python-alpine
# Install GCC (Alpine uses musl but we compile and link dependencies with GCC)
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    libstdc++

# Stage 2 - build function and dependencies
FROM python-alpine AS build-image
# Install aws-lambda-cpp build dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    build-base \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    libexecinfo-dev \
    make \
    cmake \
    libcurl \
    curl \
    gcc \
    g++
# Include global args in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
ARG RUNTIME_VERSION
# Create function directory
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Copy required files
COPY patcher.py ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY app.py ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY requirements.txt .
COPY edit_excutable.py ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Optional – Install the function's dependencies
RUN python${RUNTIME_VERSION} -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python${RUNTIME_VERSION} -m pip install -r requirements.txt --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Fix undetected_chromedriver to use in lambda
RUN cd ${FUNCTION_DIR} && cp -f patcher.py ${FUNCTION_DIR}/undetected_chromedriver
# Install Lambda Runtime Interface Client for Python
RUN python${RUNTIME_VERSION} -m pip install awslambdaric --target ${FUNCTION_DIR}

# Stage 3 - final runtime image
# Grab a fresh copy of the Python image
FROM python-alpine
# Include global arg in this stage of the build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
# Set working directory to function root directory
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# Copy in the built dependencies
COPY --from=build-image ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY edit_excutable.py /usr/bin/
RUN apk add chromium-chromedriver
RUN wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/107.0.5304.62/chromedriver_linux64.zip

#RUN python${RUNTIME_VERSION} edit_excutable.py
RUN cp /usr/bin/chromedriver ${FUNCTION_DIR}
# (Optional) Add Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator and use a script in the ENTRYPOINT for simpler local runs
ADD https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie
COPY entry.sh /
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/aws-lambda-rie /entry.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entry.sh" ]
CMD [ "app.lambda_handler" ]
```

and here is a snippet of my code that generate the error:

```
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import subprocess
import shutil
import time

BIN_DIR = "/tmp/bin"
CURR_BIN_DIR = os.getcwd()

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    if not os.path.exists(BIN_DIR):
        print("Creating bin folder")
        os.makedirs(BIN_DIR)
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + BIN_DIR
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + CURR_BIN_DIR
    print (os.environ)

    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1024x768')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    chrome_options.binary_location = "/tmp/chromedriver"
    options = {'request_storage_base_dir': '/tmp' }
    os.system("cp ./chromedriver /tmp/chromedriver")
    os.chmod("/tmp/chromedriver", 0o777)
    driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path=r"/tmp/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

I tried different versions of the runtime, chromdrive and distro version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem in the code using **driver_executable_path** argument instead of **executable_path**.

Also I changed the docker file to first install chromium browser then chromedriver

```
RUN apk add chromium
RUN apk add chromium-chromedriver
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: minimal working example here: https://github.com/filipopo/undetected-chromedriver-lambda

Looks like you are one of the only people on the internet who have successfully done this, congrats and why not make a tutorial? for everyone else who stumbled upon this question searching for a way to use undetected_chromedriver on AWS Lambda....

For now you must use version 3.4.6 of undetected_chromedriver because the newer ones import multiprocess which is not supported on Lambda (I will make a fork and PR a fix to the main repo), this version supports selenium up to version 4.9.1 I think, this version also only supports Chrome v114

I think you must use most of the arguments but change the headless one to the following, also it won't hurt to add a bit more

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
```

Just like OP you must copy chromedriver to /tmp during execution because undetected_chromedriver will try to patch it and Lambda's environment is read only excluding /tmp, but it won't work if you try to make a container with chromedriver already in /tmp because Lambda will clear /tmp at the beginning of every execution

```
### Dirty fixes for Lambda
driver_executable_path = '/tmp/chromedriver'
browser_executable_path = '/opt/chrome/chrome'

os.system(f'cp /opt/chromedriver {driver_executable_path}')
os.chmod(driver_executable_path, 0o777)

driver = uc.Chrome(chrome_options, driver_executable_path=driver_executable_path, browser_executable_path=browser_executable_path, version_main=114)
```

If you are struggling to even make headless chrome work in Lambda, the following repo may help you as it helped me :)
https://github.com/umihico/docker-selenium-lambda